# What's the meaning of the word 'there' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

In the song "[You are the reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=207X6DTY4LY)" by Calum Scott

> **There goes** my heart beating
>
> 'Cause you are the reason

What does the word "**[there](http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-there/)**" mean in this context?

Comment: Without *there*, the sentence would be incomplete. *Goes my heart beating* doesn't make any sense. *There* is used in order to make the sentence syntactically sound. It's the same as the so-called dummy it in *it is raining*.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&sxsrf=ACYBGNSIzlpYtaIwMSAMLbKVG9tLti1cRA%3A1576483673319&ei=WTv3XcWYE42flwTnwpb4DA&q=there%20goes%20meaning&oq=there%20go%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3.2.0i7i30l10.92123.92820..95651...0.4..0.216.622.0j1j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39i70i249j0j0i67.J19fNA342SQ),

> **there goes —**
>
> phrase of there
>   used to express the destruction or failure of
>   something.
>
> > *"there goes my career"*

The writer is expressing the failure of his heart beating properly, or the irregularity in its beats because of the lover.